# How do I replace a row value with the previous cell value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace values in rows with the previous row in pandas dataframe. 
I tried using:

```
p2['top3_today']=p2['top3_today'].shift()
```

AND

```
p2['top3_today']=p2['top3_today'].shift(-1)
```

But this does not work. Kindly help!

Comment: Please add expected output, to clarify why it does not work.

Comment: What does `this does not work` mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
p2['top3_today'].shift(1, axis = 0)
```

it will replace each row with the previous value, except for the first row which will be "NaN".

IF you do:

```
p2['top3_today'].shift(-1, axis = 0 )
```

it will still replace each value in a row with its previous except for the last row ("NaN")

so, unless you framed your question incorrectly, the shift() function should do what you want; unless you want to perform the shift on the "column" axis.
in this case you should change axis = 1